# Android XML reading issue (canRead() = false)

Tags: android, xml, android-sdcard, android-file

I've a problem with reading a XML file in my APP. I've tried multiple options but I'm getting error that read acces is false. I'm sure I'm using the correct path.

> XML = new File(XML, "file.xml"); 
>   Log.i("XML", "Read access:" + XML.canRead());

This does return a false, I only need to read not to write (at least, not yet..).

> System.getProperty(XML.getPath())

Returns null

I think there is a problem with the SD card (see other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12971170/1758744)). But in my app I can open diffent folders except the XML file in the last folder.

I've added the correct permission to the manifest file.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
File path:

`File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
                    + File.separator 
                    + "external_sd" 
                    + File.separator 
                    + "app"
                    + File.separator 
                    + "Games"
                    + File.separator 
                    + "Version_1" 
                    );`

I've no problem with opening the folders. In my last folder there wil be a xml which can't be opened.

I'm using part of the path in other parts of the APP and there it works..

Also the code `XML.exists()` returns false...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `getProperty()`? Check if the file exists with `XML.exists()` I doubt that you have permission problems.

Comment: What happens when you do `File file = mContext.getFileStreamPath("file.xml"());`

Comment: "in my app I can open diffent folders except the XML file in the last folder." means you can't open anything in file.xml's folder?

Comment: psot the complete path you use

Comment: If you can read other files from the external memory, it probably have nothing to do with your other issue.

Comment: Sorry it might have to do with your other issue. Please ensure at first than your physical sdcard is correctly mounted by giveing us the output of "adb shell df" from your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was related to to other issue, that one also solved this issue

all thanks for the help..