# How to find whether the SD card is present or not via code/API in Android?

Tags: android

How to get the status whether a SD card is mounted/inserted in Android device or not.
The following is always returning TRUE:

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
```

There are several post related to this, but I couldn't find a manufacturer-independent solution.

Comment: I think you can find there----->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721827/how-to-check-if-a-sd-card-has-been-inserted-to-the-tablet-or-not-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429228/check-whether-the-sd-card-is-available-or-not-programmatically

Comment: @Amarbir, thanks for reply...but the above link is also doing same check..what I mentioned in my question. So it will not solve my issue.                                        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
   
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
       }

Answer (score 1):

**Android API**: Iterate through all external storages obtainable with [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), calling [`isExternalStorageRemovable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable(java.io.File)) on each of them. When you find one, ask if it is mounted with [`getExternalStorageState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)). However, it may happen that the SD card is not used for any external storage directory and so you would not find it.

**fstab**: Parse `/etc/vold.fstab`, find mount points, ask if they are removeable with `isExternalStorageRemovable` and check their state with `getExternalStorageState`. Because it does not use public API, it may not work correctly in some versions of Android, including future ones. It may not work when the SD card is not used for any external storage either.

**mounts**: Parse `/proc/mounts` and do the same as for `fstab` but that may not work if the SD card is not used for any external storage. Or search for any partition using `vfat` but that may return false positives. `/proc/mounts` is a public Linux API so it is present in the same format everywhere. If no SD card can be found there, it is impossible to distinguish whether the SD card is unmounted or not supported at all.

However, there's really no reason to need that (and that's why there is no simple API for it). When you want to put some content in an external storage, you should use the appropriate directory provided by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, disregarding whether it is an SD card or not.